# RavenDB up multiple updates

Tags: ravendb

Is it possible to update multiple records in RavenDB - and do it in the database? I am trying to replace a particular property value in every document that's stored.

Comment: can you share any code you've tried?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible using the [patch API](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/partial-document-updates). You'll find sample bulk-update operations [in the docs](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/set-based-operations).